# I got a problem with working script at specific channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This is I think my last problem with this, because I don't how to do my script works only at specific channel this is what I tried:

```
ch = client.get_channel('my number channel id')


   if message.channel is not ch:
    return
```

And here's the error:

File "", line 101
    `if message.channel is not ch:`
                                ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Answer (score 1):

You have indentation problem (in python, indentation is how you define scope of function or class). Try this:

```
ch = client.get_channel('my number channel id')
if message.channel is not ch:
    return
```